# Is it correct to say that «pull» is kinda «merge»?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push

Is it correct to say that «push» is kinda «merge»? The only difference, that I see: «merge» is operation on my local branches, «push» is operation between local and remote branch.

Is my understanding right or not?

Answer (score 4):

`git pull` is an alias to `git fetch + git merge`.

`git fetch` updates your local repository with the changes (delta) which are downloaded from the remote repository and stored inside your local `.git` folder.

Once the fetch is over and you have all the data locally, then `git merge` occurs and merges your changes with the one from the remote.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`git pull` is defined as `git fetch + git merge`. So yes, it *is* merge.

`git push` is not a merge of any kind. It just pushes your local commits to a remote destination. If anything goes less than perfect, it refuses to continue.